What is a transformation (physical) in precise terms?
I’m reading some quantum field theory from physics (David Tong’s lecture note), but I don’t quite understand what it means to perform some transformation $x \rightarrow x’$.
I’m trying to view it in terms of manifolds, i. e. everything is in terms of charts.
I know this sounds like a stupid question, but what does it mean to transform $x$ into $x’$? Is it a function $T(x)=x’$? If so, what is the domain and codomain in of $T$? What is $x$ here? Is it a point on manifold or is it a coordinate in the coordinate domain? Is $x’$ in the same chart or a different chart?
I don’t even understand the simple spatial translation $x \rightarrow x+a$. Manifolds don’t necessarily have a vector space structure, so it is not valid to perform addition on manifold, so I guess $x$ and $a$ are coordinate in some charts, but I’m not sure.

Except for general relativity, physicists do not assume the universe is an abstract manifold. Except for relativity, the assumption is that physical space is Euclidean soace.

Despite manifolds do not assume vector space structure, you can easily define a tangent space $T_pM , \forall p \in M$ and define vector transforms in / between those spaces.

There are two kinds of transformations, whose names in Physics I forget. One would be coordinate charts transformations, think changing a frame of reference: your theory (e.g. a physical equation) should persist through these. Another is a symmetry transformation - translation is an example. These are features of the theory (e.g. a property of the Lagrangian), and are not properties of the manifold

This is easier to see in QM. An unitary transformation preserves the inner product / changes the basis, and is independent of the Hamiltonian at hand. But something a symmetry is a property related to the hamiltonian.
